# how can I extract file path from MultipartFile

Tags: java, upload, drive

I want to extract file path then can upload to google drive. How can I get the path from MultipartFile??

```
    //logger.info(""+uploadFile.getClass().getResource("").getFile().getPath());
    //System.out.println(uploadFile.getClass().getResource("").getPath());
```

also tried convert MultipartFile to File but cannot "import java.io.File" because of "import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;" cannot be compatible with. I think. already use drive.model.File a lot.

```
@Override
public int uploadFile(HttpSession session, MultipartFile uploadFile) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File fileMetadata = new File();

    Drive driveService = getCredential(session);

    fileMetadata.setName(uploadFile.getOriginalFilename());
    logger.info(uploadFile.getResource().getFile().getAbsoluteFile().getPath());
    //logger.info(""+uploadFile.getClass().getResource("").getFile().getPath());
    //System.out.println(uploadFile.getClass().getResource("").getPath());

    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("need to input file path here");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
    File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent).setFields("id").execute();
    System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

    return 0;
}
```

Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MultipartFile resource [uploadFile] cannot be resolved to absolute file path

I can get the name, size from MultipartFile that is in parameter so it is exists but how can I get the path from it??

Comment: A multipart file is just an abstraction that is used for transfers. It has the bytes, a name, and the type, etc. But it has no idea which is the source, is it really a file(bytes written on a physical drive)... You can not take this information at this point, unless you pass it somehow(meaning that you have to bundle it with the multipart at the moment of its creation). Check if [MultipartFile:: getOriginalFilename](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--) could be of any use to you.

Comment: that is my local file that I chosen for upload to drive. i gave up to get the path. thank you for advice!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a file path to upload the file anywhere. Use `multipartFile.getInputStream()` or `multipartFile.getBytes()` instead. Actually at the moment of getting the file you cann't know a path to a file (it's not a solid rule but rather a browser-dependent feature)

Comment: I want to upload the file to google drive. so i can use that library only but I cannot get path I have to upload local and get path. thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

I could not extract file path from MultipartFile directly. However I could get the getInputStream() proprety.

Then, you can use the code below considering the **inputStream** is your MultPartFile variable .getInputStream().

```
 StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader br
      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(**inputStream**))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            resultStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    }
```

After you can read the resultStringBuilder variable and you can get the value you want.

This way worked to me. I hope can helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the `CommonsMultipartResolver` from `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons` which is the implementation for

> implementation for Apache Commons FileUpload  1.2 or above.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create a `multipartResolver` bean:

```
   @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(
            @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.location}") String tmpFolder,
            @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size}") DataSize maxFileSize,
            @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size}") DataSize maxRequestSize) throws IOException {
        CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(maxRequestSize.toBytes());
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxFileSize.toBytes());
        commonsMultipartResolver.setUploadTempDir(new FileUrlResource(tmpFolder));
        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }
```

Then you should get a `CommonsMultipartFile` as implementation of the `MultipartFile` interface in your method and you can get the absolute path of the `MultipartFile`:

```
File storeLocation = uploadFile.getFileItem().getStoreLocation();
```